# Extent SpatialPoints in to SpatialPolygon in the shape of an ellipse

Tags: buffer, spatial, ellipse

I would like to generate a buffer in the shape of an ellipse around each point in a SpatialPointsDataFrame, meaning in the end I would like to have a polygon for each point in my spatial data frame that is shaped like an ellipse extending the original point 130 km latitudinal and 70 km longitudinal.

I tried using the st_ellipse function but run into the issue that the resulting polygon plots in a random location instead of as a buffer around the point it was generated for.
Maybe someone has an idea, what might be going wrong here or has a suggestion for a different way to generate an ellipse around a spatial point.

Please see the code I used below.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
# example data frame

ID<-"point1"
longitude<- -120.628
latitude<- 36.64

spp<-data.frame(ID,longitude,latitude)

projection<-"+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs" 

# convert to st object to be able to use st_ellipse function

stp<-st_as_sf(spp, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))

# assign same projection as background
stp<-stp %>% st_set_crs(st_crs(world2_proj))

# generate ellipse around point (70 km longitudinal; 130 km latitudinal)
stp_elp<-st_ellipse(stp, ex=70000, ey=130000)

#convert back to spatial polygon
elp_poly<-as(stp_elp, "Spatial")

# convert into a SpatialPolygonDataFrame
df<- data.frame(id = getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(elp_poly))
row.names(df) <- getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(elp_poly)

spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(elp_poly, data =df)

# change projection to match to background
crs(spdf)<-projection
```

both SpatialPolygonsDataFrame have the same projection:

> spdf
> class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
> features    : 1
> extent      : -70120.63, 69469.03, -129772.7, 129846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs         : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs
> variables   : 1
> names       :  id
> value       : ID1

> world2_proj
> class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
> features    : 209
> extent      : -12240565, 11932463, -12523922, 11616224  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs         : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs
> variables   : 3
> names       :        NAME, GMI_CNTRY,             REGION
> min values  : Afghanistan,       AFG,         Antarctica
> max values  :    Zimbabwe,       ZWE, Sub Saharan Africa

```
# But when I try to plot them on top of each other, the new polygon (in red) plots in a random location away from the original location (blue cross).


# plot on top of background to see if function worked

plot(crop(world2_proj,e))
plot(spdf, add=T, col="red")
```

[The new polygon (in red), plots in a random location away from the location that was used to generate the ellipse from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnfIH.png)

Comment: Can you provide or link to the data for the `world2_proj` object?

Comment: First thing I notice is that your projection is longitude and latitude. Your call to `st_ellipse` is buffering by 7000 degrees latitude not 70 km as your comment would suggest.